# AWS Glue dynamicframe writing csv to s3 with null

Tags: dataframe, csv, apache-spark, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I have a glue job that is writing a dynamicframe to a CSV in s3 but for some reason the nulls are being removed. What is a good solution to resolve this?

Desired Output in CSV:

```
user_id, example_assignment, example_product
null, null, null
null, llama, null
null, null, feed
```

Current Output in CSV:

```
user_id, example_assignment, example_product
,,
,llama,
,,feed
```

Glue Write Csv:

```
glueContext.getSinkWithFormat(
      connectionType = "s3",
      options = example_path, 
      transformationContext = "example_transformation", 
      format = "csv"
    ).writeDynamicFrame(exampleDF)
```

Comment: Have you tried https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-transforms-fillmissingvalues.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So currently Glue does not provide an [emptyValues option like Spark](https://mrpowers.medium.com/sparks-treatment-of-empty-strings-and-null-values-in-csv-files-80748893451f) does on write.

You could either use the Spark API directly, or fill those empty values beforehand with, for example, the aforementioned [FillMissingValue Class](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-transforms-fillmissingvalues.html) from Glue.